# Why is this the right answer to this orbit question?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Here is the question i am curious about:

> #### Exercise 3.
>
> Find the number of orbits in the set $ \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 \} $ under the action of the cyclic subgroup $ \langle (1356) \rangle $ of $ S_8 $. [Recall that $ S_n $ acts on $ [ n ] := \{ 1, 2, \dots, n \} $ by permutation: Each element $ \sigma \in S_n $ is a permutation of $ [ n ] $, i.e. a bijective function $ \sigma : [ n ] \to [ n ] $. This induces the action $ S_n \times [ n ] \to [ n ], (\sigma, k) \mapsto \sigma(k) $.]

I have that the answer is $5$ orbits, one being $\{1,3,5,6\}$ and the rest are singleton sets that are 'fixed'.

Im not sure i even completely understand what the group action actually is. Would someone be able to write it out for me and how we get what the orbits actually are?

I know that the orbit is defined as $Gx=\{g.x|g \in G\}.$ After a group acts on a set do we get an element of the set again?

I know that the orbits must partition the set.

Comment: Do you understand how the group of permutations of $\{1,\dots,8\}$ acts on $\{1,\dots,8\}$? Also, I would rather denote the orbit $\{1,3,5,6\}$ since this is a set.

Comment: I dont think i do, can youve give an example?

Comment: Ok, $(1,2)\cdot 2=1$, $(1,2)\cdot 1=2$ and $(1,2)\cdot 3=3$.

Comment: To answer your question: yes, after a group acts on a set you get back elements of the set. An action of $G$ on $X$ is a map $G \times X \to X$, that sends $g$ and $x$ to the element $g\cdot x $ of $X$.

Comment: @pullofthemoon Do you know what the notation $(1,2)$ represents?

Answer (score 2):

The action of $S_n$ is by permutations. So is the action of a subgroup. $(1356)$ is the permutation that send $1 \mapsto 3, 3\mapsto 5, 5 \mapsto 6, 6 \mapsto 1$ and leaves all other numbers fixed. $\langle(1356)\rangle$ is just the subgroup of $S_n$ generated by this element, which consists of all its powers:

$$ \langle(1356)\rangle = \{ (1356)^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}_0\} = \{ \text{id},(1356), (15)(36), (1653)\}.$$

You should make yourself comfortable with these notations and facts (they are certainly explained somewhere in your reference).

Now, clearly $\{1,3,5,6\}$ is an orbit under the action of $\langle(1356)\rangle$, because you can send each element to each other element and they never get sent to something outside this set. All other numbers are fixed by all the permutations in $\langle(1356)\rangle$, hence their orbits are just the singletons $\{2\},\{4\},\{7\},\{8\}$.

Comment: That is very helpful. I think the root of my problem still is that i don't actually understand what the group action is. For example...Why is $(1,3,5,6).2=2?$ Can you give an explanation of what it is?

Comment: Writing $(1356)$ is just a shorthand to denote the bijection that sends $1,3,5,6$ in a cycle and leaves all other elements fixed. In the same way, the permutation $(12)(58)(347)$ exchanges the places of $1$ and $2$; of $5$ and $8$; sends $3 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 7 \mapsto 4$; and leaves $6$ fixed. It is just a problem of notation, you just need to work out some examples. Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation). (It might be helpful to read the rest of the Wikipedia page before).

Comment: That makes sense thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let's set:
$$G:=\langle(1356)\rangle=\{(1356),(15)(36),(1653),()\}\tag1$$
By definition of orbit under the action of $G$ as group of permutations ("natural"), and $(1)$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
O(1) &= \{\sigma(1), \sigma\in G\}=\{3,5,6,1\} \\
O(2) &= \{\sigma(2), \sigma\in G\}=\{2\} \\
O(3) &= \{\sigma(3), \sigma\in G\}=\{5,6,1,3\}=O(1) \\
O(4) &= \{\sigma(4), \sigma\in G\}=\{4\} \\
O(5) &= \{\sigma(5), \sigma\in G\}=\{6,1,3,5\}=O(1) \\
O(6) &= \{\sigma(6), \sigma\in G\}=\{1,3,5,6\}=O(1) \\
O(7) &= \{\sigma(7), \sigma\in G\}=\{7\} \\
O(8) &= \{\sigma(8), \sigma\in G\}=\{8\} \\
\end{alignat}
Therefore, five orbits overall.